# Is there any way to adjust the format of folded lines in vim?

Tags: vim, folding

Now my folded lines look like this:

```
+-- 123 lines: doSomeStuff();--------------------------
+-- 345 lines: doSomeOtherStuff();---------------------
```

I would like to remove everything before the actual contents of a line (+-- xxx lines:), make it more like Notepad++/Eclipse visuals way — now it's too hard to read, and I actually don't care how much lines I have under a certain fold :) So are there any commands for adjusting the format of folded lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `foldtext` function which romainl already mentioned returns a string to be displayed in a closed fold (in other words, that - what you see).

You can modify the fold function to show whatever you find interesting. For example,

```
function! MyFoldText() " {{{
    let line = getline(v:foldstart)

    let nucolwidth = &fdc + &number * &numberwidth
    let windowwidth = winwidth(0) - nucolwidth - 3
    let foldedlinecount = v:foldend - v:foldstart

    " expand tabs into spaces
    let onetab = strpart('          ', 0, &tabstop)
    let line = substitute(line, '\t', onetab, 'g')

    let line = strpart(line, 0, windowwidth - 2 -len(foldedlinecount))
    let fillcharcount = windowwidth - len(line) - len(foldedlinecount)
    return line . '…' . repeat(" ",fillcharcount) . foldedlinecount . '…' . ' '
endfunction " }}}
set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

will return something similar to this

```
" Basic settings --------------------------------------------- {{{...              6 ...
```

meaning 6 lines are in the fold (including the one with the closing fold marker)

Answer (score 2):

`:help fold-foldtext` has all the info you need.